# How to replace all the existing expenseCategory saved in Core Data which are having same expense categoryName

Tags: swiftui, core-data

For example I have number of expenses with “Food” expenseCategory which are saved in core Data.  When I click the save Button under EditExpenseCategory view I want to change all the existing Food expenseCategory to “Lunch”  instead of editing one by one.

Following is the code for editing the ExpenseCategory for the reference. With the save button I only able to update existing index but not other indices of  “Food” expenseCategory.

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditExpenseCategory: View {
    @State var expenseCategory: String = ""
    @StateObject var item: Item = Item()
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            
            TextField("Expense Category", text: $expenseCategory)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            
            Button {
                item.expenseCategory = expenseCategory
                do {
                   try viewContext.save()
                    dismiss()
                } catch {
                    print("error saving: \(error)")
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the code for the reference.
The contentView is the view to display all the expenses.

The EditExpenseCategory view created to update existing ExpenseCategory.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.expenseDate, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    @State var addExpenseSheet: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        EditExpenseCategory(expenseCategory: item.expenseCategory ?? "", item: item)
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.expenseCategory ?? "")
                            Text(item.expenseDate ?? Date(), style: .date)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button {
                        addExpenseSheet.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")

                    }

                    
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $addExpenseSheet) {
                CreateExpenses()
            }
        }
    }


}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

The CreateExpenses view is to add new expense and save to CoreData

```
import SwiftUI

struct CreateExpenses: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State var expenseName: String = ""
    @State var expenseDate: Date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker("Expense Date", selection: $expenseDate, displayedComponents: .date)
            
            TextField("Expense Name", text: $expenseName)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            
            Button {
                let newExpense = Item(context: viewContext)
                newExpense.expenseCategory = expenseName
                newExpense.expenseDate = expenseDate
                do {
                   try viewContext.save()
                    dismiss()
                } catch {
                    print("error saving: \(error)")
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)

            
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

How could I update all the existing category which are matching the same expenseCategory name .

I tried grouping ExpenseCategory using @SectionedFetchRequest and .replacingOccurrences but I wasn’t able to edit all expensCategory with the same name.

Comment: Look into batch update, also `@StateObject` is for initialization of `ObservableObject`s, `@ObservedObject` is for passing around (most appropriate for CoreData objects).

Comment: Thanks. I will check batch update. I changed StateObject to @ObservedObject.